# Print all diffrent patterns from a line if there are any using grep/awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

```
myapp.log.2015-03-31:in<username|password>version=1.1.8,type=Login
```

I want to print only "username" and "version" from this line. If I use

```
grep -o "username"
```

it will print only *usernames*. Similarly if I use

```
grep -o "version.*,"
```

it will print out all version numbers. Is there any way that I could print both *username* and *version* number together?

like

```
"username" version=1.1.8,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
grep -oP "username|version.*(?=,)"
```

This will omit the comma after version: `version=1.1.8`

If you don't want that then simply:

```
grep -oP "username|version.*,"
#grep -oE "username|version.*,"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex alternation:

```
s='myapp.log.2015-03-31:in<username|password>version=1.1.8,type=Login'
grep -Eo "username|version.*," <<< "$s" | tr '\n' ' '
username version=1.1.8,
```